# How to access data from another kotlin file in the same project?

Tags: android

[Kotlin file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STUYE.png)

[Kotlin file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk1JG.png)

In a nutshell, how do we extract data from another Kotlin file in the same project?

Comment: Could you please paste your code in a properly formatted way instead of as images?

Comment: Code needs to be posted as Text not screenshots. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want extract data from kotlin file 2 while in Kotlin file 1

```
fun main() {
    val kotlinFile2 = KotlinFile2()
    smartTvDevice.turnOn()
}
```

Were turnOn() is a method in KotlinFile2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).